# Downlaod a csv file from linux server to windows server

Tags: csv, download, remote-server

actually, I have this bat file script that download a CSV file from Linux server via URL , transfer to an excel file using a jar, and save it in a directory on windows server

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar HTTPDownload_fat.jar http://lxhv1ileoweb01:8180/whoiswho/export D:\WhoIsWhoImport\user.xlsx 8180 lxhv1ileoweb01
```

how could I update this bat to keep the file as it is ( CSV ) without transferring to excel , just downloaded and save it on the other server

thanks in advance

Comment: any idea please ?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl